# select2 initSelection does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

```
$('.select2.base-product').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: {
        url: "@Url.Action("GetBaseProducts", "Promotion")",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                searchTerm: term, // search term,
                pageSize: 15,
                pageNum: page
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
            return { results: data.items };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    initSelection: function(element, callback) {
        var id = $(element).val();
        var formatId = $(element).attr('data-formatid');
            if(id.length > 0) {
                $.ajax('@Url.Action("GetBaseCategoryById", "Promotion")', {
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        id: id, formatId: formatId
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data.items);
                    callback(data.items);
                });
            }
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) { return markup; } // let our custom formatter work
});
```

Hello, I have a big problem with initializaion the select2 input. My action GetBaseCategoryById return a object, example

```
[Object]
0: Object
id: "33:2613"
text: "Naklejki: Okrągła"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

For me result like this is correct for select2 but input is empty. Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: "but input is empty"?

Comment: what input? data? what do you get if you alert(data) in done of the GetBaseCategoryById action.

Comment: select2 input is empty. I showed console.log. In alert is Object object

Comment: I suggest you include your html.

Comment: are you using select2 4.0? in that case , initselection has been deprecated